# Store any string with any character encoding in MySQL and retrieve them

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding, collation

In PHP, how can I store a string from an input field in a MySQL database, and then retrieve them and display them on a page exactly like it was typed into the input field? It shouldn't matter what type of character encoding is used, even if it's a Chinese or something like that. What functions do I need to apply to the strings in PHP? And what collation do I need to use for my database?

Comment: Just use UTF-8 [all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the character encoding collation in your mysql database:
e.g.

```
utf8_general_ci
```

and you need to set the encoding of your page to display the driven content as they are:
e.g.

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8; http-equiv=Content-Type');
```